# Is there a way to tell what version of Sitecore Cloud xDB is currently supporting?

Tags: xdb

I upgraded our environment to Sitecore 8.2 Update 2.   I now am getting the following error on startup.

```
ManagedPoolThread #6 17:01:24 INFO  Cache created: 'SqlDataProvider - Property data(production)' (max size: 500KB, running total: 5756MB)
8228 17:01:25 INFO  xDB Cloud - Get xDB-set with License Id: '20150130061746' - Deployment Id: 'JDA20150130061746' Attempt 2 of 5
8228 17:01:30 INFO  xDB Cloud - Get xDB-set with License Id: '20150130061746' - Deployment Id: 'JDA20150130061746' Attempt 3 of 5
8228 17:01:35 INFO  xDB Cloud - Get xDB-set with License Id: '20150130061746' - Deployment Id: 'JDA20150130061746' Attempt 4 of 5
8228 17:01:40 INFO  xDB Cloud - Get xDB-set with License Id: '20150130061746' - Deployment Id: 'JDA20150130061746' Attempt 5 of 5
8228 17:01:40 ERROR xDB Cloud - Exception during initializing occurred
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Sitecore.Cloud.RestClient.IRestResponse`1<!!0>> Sitecore.Cloud.RestClient.IRestClient.ExecuteAsync(Sitecore.Cloud.RestClient.IRestRequest)'.
   at Sitecore.Cloud.Xdb.DiscoveryServiceClient.GetXdbSet(String licenseId, String deploymentId, String sitecoreVersion, String cloudXdbAssemblyVersion, String cloudSearchAssemblyVersion, String deploymentType)
   at Sitecore.Cloud.Xdb.DiscoveryServiceClient.<GetXdbSet>b__0()
   at Sitecore.Cloud.Xdb.Retryer.Execute[T](Func`1 task, Func`2 stopOnException, String message, Int32 retryNum, TimeSpan retryInterval)
   at Sitecore.Cloud.Xdb.DiscoveryServiceClient.GetXdbSet()
   at Sitecore.Cloud.Xdb.UpdateXdbConnectionStrings.Process(PipelineArgs args)
8228 17:01:40 ERROR xDB Cloud - xDB Cloud initialization failed. Please contact Sitecore Support via http://support.sitecore.net
8228 17:01:40 FATAL xDB Cloud - xDB Cloud initialization failed. Please contact Sitecore Support via http://support.sitecore.net
8228 17:01:40 INFO  xDB Cloud - Initialization failed
8228 17:01:40 INFO  [Analytics]: Started background service for 'maintenanceService'.
```

As nothing else changed in the environment other than the upgrade I was curious if it was because 8.2 Update 2 support hadn't been deployed to their cloud xDB yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the writing of this answer, Sitecore's xDB Cloud Service is not compatible currently with Sitecore XP 8.2 Update 2.

### Supported Versions

According to the [Compatibility Table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/966080) for xDB Cloud, the  following versions are currently supported:

- Sitecore 8.0 Update 6
- Sitecore 8.0 Update 7
- Sitecore 8.1 Update 1
- Sitecore 8.1 Update 2
- Sitecore 8.1 Update 3
- Sitecore 8.2 Initial Release

### Unsupported Versions

- All of Sitecore 7.5 and below
- Sitecore 8.0 Initial Release through Update 5
- Sitecore 8.1 Initial Release
- Sitecore 8.2 Update-1 (Coming February 2017)
- Sitecore 8.2 Update-2 (Coming February 2017)

Comment: Thanks!   I wish they had that info right on their download page.  Instead it says "xDB Cloud support will be released approximately 6 weeks after the release of the Sitecore Experience Platform.".  If that were true support for 8.2 Update 1 should have already released at the beginning of this month and 8.2 Update 2 should be just a week or so away.